# JS и динамический идентификатор

Tags: php, javascript

У меня есть js-код, который меняет следующие поля, в зависимости от выбранного ранее поля.

```
$('#types').on('change', function() {
    var selection = $(this).val();
    $('div#values > div').hide();
    $('#'+selection+' *').prop('disabled',false);
    $("#"+selection).show();
```

Здесь указан идентификатор `#types`. Проблема в том, что у меня динамическая форма. Первая форма у меня идет с `id="types"`, а следующие формы уже идут `id="types"+1` , то есть `types1,types2,...`
Как мне указать в JS-коде то, что id у меня меняется?? 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот когда 1 открыто то все норм, но когда открываю 2 то уже не работает..
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
То есть, как в php будет в этом случае - `types[]`
А как будет тогда в js ?? Или я не в ту сторону копаю?

Вот весь код, если так будет понятнее

```
 <?php DynamicFormWidget::begin([
    'widgetContainer' => 'dynamicform_wrapper', // required: only alphanumeric characters plus "_" [A-Za-z0-9_]
    'widgetBody' => '.container-items2', // required: css class selector
    'widgetItem' => '.item2', // required: css class
    'limit' => 10, // the maximum times, an element can be cloned (default 999)
    'min' => 1, // 0 or 1 (default 1)
    'insertButton' => '.add-item2', // css class
    'deleteButton' => '.remove-item2', // css class
    'model' => $clientObject[0],
    'formId' => 'dynamic-form',
    'formFields' => [
        'type_id',
    ],
]);
$list = ArrayHelper::map(\common\models\objects\ObjectType::find()
    ->where(['not', ['parent_id' => NULL]])->all(), 'id', 'name');
?>

<div class="container-items2"><!-- widgetContainer -->
    <?php foreach ($clientObject as $i => $objects): ?>
    <div class="item2 panel panel-default"><!-- widgetBody -->
        <div class="panel-body">
            <button type="button" class="add-item2 btn btn-success btn-xs"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i></button>
            <button type="button" class="remove-item2 btn btn-danger btn-xs"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></i></button>
            <?= $form->field($objects, "[{$i}]type_id")->dropDownList($list, ['id' => 'types'])->label(false) ?>
            <div id="values">
                <div id="3" style="display:none;">
                    <?= $form->field($objects, "[{$i}]count_room")->textInput() ?>
                    <?= $form->field($objects, "[{$i}]count_meter")->textInput() ?>
                    <?= $form->field($objects, "[{$i}]is_repair")->checkbox() ?>
                    <?= $form->field($objects, "[{$i}]is_new_building")->dropDownList([
                        'Сдан' => 'Сдан',
                        'Не сдан' => 'Не сдан',
                        'Вторичный рынок' => 'Вторичный рынок',
                    ]) ?>
                </div>
                <div id="4" style="display:none;">
                    <?= $form->field($objects, "[{$i}]count_meter")->textInput() ?>
                    <?= $form->field($objects, "[{$i}]count_hundredth")->textInput() ?>
                    <?= $form->field($objects, "[{$i}]is_repair")->checkbox() ?>
                </div>
                <div id="5" style="display:none;">
                    <?= $form->field($objects, "[{$i}]count_hundredth")->textInput() ?>
                </div>

                <div id="6" style="display:none;">
                    <?= $form->field($objects, "[{$i}]type")->textInput() ?>
                </div>
                <div id="7" style="display:none;">
                    <?= $form->field($objects, "[{$i}]count_room")->textInput() ?>
                </div>
                <div id="9" style="display:none;">
                    <?= $form->field($objects, "[{$i}]type")->textInput() ?>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php DynamicFormWidget::end(); ?>
    <?php
    //script JS
    $script = <<< JS
   $('#types').on('change', function() {
    var selection = $(this).val();
    $('div#values > div').hide();
    $('#'+selection+' *').prop('disabled',false);
    $("#"+selection).show();
});
JS;
    $this->registerJs($script, View::POS_END);
    ?>
```

Comment: добавьте в таг `<form class="typesclass" ...`, а в коде: `$('.typesclass').on('change', function() { ...`

Comment: Немного не понял, просто поменять id на class? Так результат тот же. Мне кажется нужно как-то поставить счетчик который прибавлял бы +1 к js-коду в месте, где идентификатор - $('#types')

Comment: посмотрите ответ, может там понятнее

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте селектор ["Атрибут начинается с..."](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

```
$("[id^='types']").on('change', function() {
    ...
}
```